# How can I remove "http://", "https://" and "www." from a URL using mod rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove "http://" and "https://" from the URL. I would also like to remove the "www." part from it as well. All using mod rewrite / .htaccess. Most related answers I found here are using PHP or JavaScript.

```
e.g, 
"http://www.example.com" should become "example.com"
"https://example.com" should become "example.com"
"www.example.com" should become "example.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `http://` and `https://` are protocol specifiers. The browser can hide them for a user, but they cannot be removed from the URL by modrewrite.

For apache modrewrite to strip the `www.`, use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```